# Was the ROS gpg key supposed to change? Bionic now uses F42ED6FBAB17C654 as of June 6, 2019

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My server stopped updating, when I investigated I found that at least the Bionic packages seem to be signed with a new public key. The installation instructions still specify the old key, was this change intentional?

New key: F42ED6FBAB17C654

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325201/was-the-ros-gpg-key-supposed-to-change?-bionic-now-uses-f42ed6fbab17c654-as-of-june-6,-2019/) by [Curt](https://answers.ros.org/users/12666/curt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually I see that the installer instructions have been updated so I guess someone knew this was going to change.

The subtle failures this caused was a bit unexpected.

---

Originally posted by [Curt](https://answers.ros.org/users/12666/curt/) with karma: 26 on 2019-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2019-06-10**:
The reason is described in here: https://answers.ros.org/question/325039/apt-update-fails-cannot-install-pkgs-key-not-working/

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-11**:
This is indeed a duplicate of #q325039.

> The subtle failures this caused was a bit unexpected.

There have been multiple posts about this -- and the preparations -- on ROS Discourse.

It's a breaking change, but it was well announced on the appropriate channels for this type of thing.